# which datepicker event will occur when i hide the datepicker?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have the daetpicker that has binded to textbox. I just want to know when i hide the datepicker, which datepicker event will fire.

```
$('#datepicker-section').datepicker("hide");
```

Below are the some Datepicker events:

```
onSelect()
onClose()
```

Please help me on this. I tried will onClose event it didn't fired.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle with an example of how to use the onClose with datepicker - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xP8w5/).

When the datepicker is closed after selection of a date, the named function after the onClose: line is fired.

JS

```
$('#mydate').datepicker({
                         onClose: closeme
                         });

function closeme()
{
  alert('closed');
}
```